# Unable to to stream FFMPEG

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, streaming

I am having a simple problem that i would normally be able to solve, i am sure the solution must be obvious But for some reason i unable to find it. I am streaming with FFMPEG to a html video tag but i keep getting this error.

```
 GET http://localhost:8080/listen.ogg 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is my simple code.

```
<?php
      $cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "exercise.mp4" -f ogg http://localhost:8080/listen.ogg';
      $descriptors = array(
          0 => array("pipe", "r"),
          1 => array("pipe", "w")
      );
      $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptors, $pipes);

     ?>

<P>plaaayyyinnng</p>
<video name="video" id="video" width="360" height="180" controls>
  <source src="http://localhost:8080/listen.ogg"> type="video/ogg">
  <p> Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
</video>
```

The server is running (Xampp), the command executes as well.
I would appreciate any help thanks.

Comment: Can you listen to the stream via other methods (VLC player, etc.) ?

Comment: no i can't via vlc..

Comment: Then something must be wrong with your streaming setup, either the file, or the command (why do both read AND write pipe?) or maybe your server setup (try what @Hafte Nigus suggested), until you can verify that the stream works without a browser. Once that works, you have at least excluded one possible error source.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add mime type video/ogg to your xampp\apache\conf\mime.types or .htaccess file.